# Compact coadjoint orbits

Tags: lie-groups, coadjoint-orbit

The following statement is from the article [Compact Coadjoint Orbits](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306336) by John Rawnsley:

> If $\mathcal{O}$ is a compact coadjoint orbit for the group $G$ then there is a closed normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ which fixes each point of $\mathcal{O}$, and such
> that $G/H$ is a compact semisimple Lie group in such a way that $\mathcal{O}$ is the sum of a $G$-fixed element of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ and a coadjoint orbit of $G/H$ pulled back to $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

I don't have any clue how to prove this statement, any help please !

Comment: What is $G$? I tried to check the paper, but the only paper MSN comes up with is [Cahen, Gutt and Rawnsley - Preferred invariant symplectic connections on compact coadjoint orbits](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1709045).  Is that the one?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431284/compact-coadjoint-orbits#comment1110042_431284), ah, it's an [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306336), and $G$ is a connected Lie group.  I have edited in the link.  The statement is what the paper *proves* (Theorem 3); the whole paper is the proof.  It doesn't seem meant to be obvious.  Neat result, though!

Comment: Thank you so much @LSpice for pointing this out! Well, I must admit that I have asked this question when I was trying to browse this article among others in order to understand your comment to my last question  that we may assume that $G$ is semisimple since the space $\mathfrak{g}_{\pm \alpha}$ is not changed by passing to adjoint action! At first I thought I understood it, but when I have tried to write down details I realized that I didn't! Could you please point out a reference where I can find more details about it or give me a proof please ?

Comment: [Sure](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1110052)$\newcommand\pa{{\pm\alpha}}\newcommand\z{\mathfrak z}\newcommand\g{\mathfrak g}$; it's nothing deep. You can also assume instead that $G$ is simply connected. We have a finite cover $Z \times G' \to G$, where $G'$ is the derived group of $G$ (or the sc cover of it) and $Z$ is the maximal central torus, hence an isomorphism $\z \oplus \g' \to \g$.  Since $\z$ is central, we have that $\z_\pa = 0$ for all $\alpha$, so $\g'_\pa \to \g_\pa$ is an isomorphism. […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1110060)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1110059) For algebraic groups, I'd say then to take the adjoint quotient $\mathbf G' \to \mathbf G'/(\mathbf Z \cap \mathbf G')$. For real groups the real points of the adjoint quotient are not necessarily the adjoint quotient of the real points; but for complex groups these notions coincide, so perhaps for compact groups too. I don't know enough about compact groups to say.  But at worst $G'/(Z \cap G')$ is an open subgroup of the adjoint quotient, so their Lie algebras match torus-equivariantly, so their weight spaces match.

Comment: I'm not familiar with some notions you have used like derived group and adjoint quotient, I'll try to read more about them and then come back and try to understand your proof, but anyway I'm really grateful for your help and for your patience with my questions.

Comment: [Sure](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1110070).  The derived group = commutator group is generated by commutators $g h g^{-1}h^{-1}$ for $g, h \in G$.  The adjoint quotient of a reductive (incl. semisimple) group is the quotient by its centre. (Again, I am conflating algebraic-group notions with abstract-group notions; I think this is OK for compact groups, but, at worst, I am off by an open subgroup.) Questions about those notions might be better at MSE; or feel free to e-mail me (you can find my e-mail on my home page, available at my [profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2383)).